# Сохранение страницы в файл

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webkit

Приветствую!
Интересует один вопрос. Начал ковырять node.js (node-webkit) желая завернуть в эту оболочку форму по работе. Почитал о работе с файловой системой (чтение, запись в файл и т.д), но все о тхт. 
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы открыв приложение, основой которой является html форма управляемая js, после ее заполнения сохранить заполненную страницу в формате .html? Если есть варианты, то в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Scripting.FileSystemObject http://www.script-coding.com/WSH/FileSystemObject.html

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь данное решение через IE работает только

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно, чтобы html-форму можно было открыть в любом браузере, нужно либо чтобы всё необходимое (стили, скрипты) содержалось в странице без ссылок внешние файлы, либо все дополнительные файлы копировать в то же расположение (в подпапку), что и сам файл. Второй вариант менее предпочтителен, т.к. в последствии связь может потеряться (например файл переместят в другое место отдельно от папки).

В первом случае нам надо получить содержимое страницы в строку и сохранить её. Если надо сохранить заполненную форму, нужно записать установленные значения элементов формы в атрибут `value`. Вот набросок кода:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('form').getElementsByTagName('input'); //берем все инпуты
for (var i in a){
    if(!a.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    inputs[i].setAttribute('value', inputs[0].value)
}
//схожим образом нужно проинициализировать также select'ы, чекбоксы и т.д.
var content = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' + document.documentElement.outerHTML; //получаем код страницы
var fs = require('fs'); //модуль fs доступен "из коробки"

fs.writeFile('path/to/form.html', content, (err) => {
  if (err) ... // обрабатывваем ошибку
  else ... //сообщаем об успешном сохранении
});
```

Во втором случае нам надо скопировать ещё и сопутсвующие файлы. Их можно взять из текущей рабочей папки проекта. Набросок:

```
var projectDir = process.cwd(); // размещение текущего проекта
fs.mkdir('path/to/folder', (err) => {  // создаем подпапку
  fs.readdir(projectDir + '/sources', (err, files) => {
    // копируем все файлы из директории sources
    files.forEach( (file) => {
            fs.createReadStream(projectDir+'/sources/'+file)
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('path/to/folder'+file)); 
            // существуют модули, упрощающие эту задачу, напимер ncp
        })      
    })
  }
});
```

(В реальной жизни необходимо всё это проверять на ошибки. Можно обернуть, например, в промисы, чтобы не городить "лестницу коллбэков". Плюс наверняка папка ресурсов будет включать подкатегории, для этого можно написать рекурсивную функцию)

Также почти наверняка придётся обновлять пути к ресурсам в коде. В простейшем случае это можно сделать регуляркой:

```
var content = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' + 
    document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(/sub\/path/g, 'new/path');
```

Comment: Благодарю!!! Очень помог) Я правда чуть перекрутил for после получения input'ов и все заработало, а до этого выдавало ошибку. По сути оно даже было и не нужно. Форму заполнения я не сохраняю, а сохраняю лист с областями output'ов. Остается только сделать, чтобы пользователь сам задавал имя сохраняемого файла)

Comment: В nw.js для этого используются файловые инпуты (`<input type=”file”>`), они имеют расширенный по сравнению с html функционал. [документация](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Changes%20to%20DOM/#fileinputvalue) (англ)

Answer (score 2):

Для сохранения данных из заполненной формы используйте json, это гораздо лучше чем хранить html код страницы. Json легко преобразуется в js объект и обратно - это очень удобно. Вам понадобится fs для ноды и выглядеть это будет примерно так:

Установка fs:

```
npm install fs --save-dev
```

Далее в скрипте:

```
    var fs = require('fs');

    // запись в json
    fs.writeFile('jsonFileName.json', JSON.stringify({ field1: "value1", field2: "value2", field3: "value3" }, null, 4));

    // доступ к файлу с json
    var json = require('jsonFileName.json');
```

Comment: Способ приемлемый! Почему html, потому что каждая заполненная страница содержит уникальные данный. Сохраняется это все под именами 9001.html, 9002.html, 4563.html, и т.д. В последующем с каждой страницы производиться печать на бланк, поэтому необходима разметка вся.

Comment: @Kirill, но ведь разметка у вас всегда одна - это форма. Берёте данные из json, заполняете форму - и на печать.